# Selecting Value Between a Range of Values in hive

Tags: hive, conditional-statements, where-clause

Select rates in rate tables and the values are between two currencies
[image]
I use subquery in where condition, but Hive does not support them

select r1.currency_code,r1.rate

from rate r1

where r1.rate >= (select r2.rate from rate r2 where r2.currency_code='GBP' )

and r1.rate<=(select r3.rate from rates r3 where r3.currency_code='ILS')

The rate between GBP and ILS should be select, but hive does not support the query

Answer (score 1):

Using conditional aggregation to get gbp and ils rates into columns before filtering.

```
select base_currency,currency_code,rate
from (select r.*
            ,max(case when currency_code='GBP' then rate end) over(partition by base_currency) as gbp_rate
            ,max(case when currency_code='ILS' then rate end) over(partition by base_currency) as ils_rate
      from rate r
      where base_currency = 'USD'
     ) r
where rate >= gbp_rate and rate <= ils_rate
```

Comment: +----------------+----------------+-------+--+
| base_currency  | currency_code  | rate  |
+----------------+----------------+-------+--+
+----------------+----------------+-------+--+